# Make ajax request run asynchronously at the server with result update

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF web application using Primefaces 4 running with Java 6 on a Tomcat 7. I have working ajax calls and all the shiny stuff the frameworks provide but I'm stuck at making an ajax request that needs long processing at the server-side really asynchronous.

```
public void onMyButtonClicked() {
    try {
        doSomethingThatTakesLong();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        final FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null,
            new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Exception caught", "Explanatory message"));
    }
}
```

Whenever my user clicks the fancy button, something that really takes a long time happens. Unfortunately, something may even go wrong and I need to display an error message. This is all working so far.

What I need to change is simple: I want the ajax call (button clicked) to return immediately, so the user can proceed fiddling around, and pop-up the error message some time later - once the long-taking thingy is done. Just putting everything into an `ExecutorService` using a `Runnable` doesn't seem to work, though. At the very least, the `FacesContext` isn't available/working from the new thread.

I can't imagine I'm the first one having this problem. Yet, I can't seem to find a solution. Is there anything like a best-practice out there or am I missing something obvious that Primefaces or JSF are providing for these kinds of circumstances?

For the record, I know about PrimePush. This may be the solution for pushing back an error message if necessary. But how do I handle the threading and when and how would I check whether an error message is available to display?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you're on the right path. `FacesContext` is only available within request scope, more specifically within the thread that handles the request (since `FacesContext` is thread-local), i.e. certainly not within your `Runnable`. But you can, of course, inject it into your `Runnable`.

For the error message, `PrimePush` should work just fine. Given an `ExecutorService` try something like this:

```
public void onMyButtonClicked() {
    final FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // You can probably use facesContext here
                doSomethingThatTakesLong();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                final PushContext pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();
                pushContext.push("/errors", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Exception caught", "Explanatory message"));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now set-up your `PrimePush` to do whatever you want on the `/errors` channel, probably update your Growl via javascript or something.

Comment: Thx! For some reason there severity isn't transmitted or ignore or whatever but since it's only about error messages in my case, I can just hard-code it in my js snippet that shows the growl.